# Universal Cover of wedge sums of spaces?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was wondering if there is some general prescription for picturing the universal cover of $X \vee Y$ for nice enough $X$ and $Y$. (Say, path-connected, locally path-connected and semilocally simply connected).

In the case where one space is simply connected, I think I have an answer. Take $S^2 \vee S^1$, where they meet at the point $x_0$; if we start with the helix above the circle and attach a copy of $S^2$ to each point in the fiber $p^{-1}(x_0)$, that is the universal cover. I think this should work for any simply connected $X$ wedged onto anything else.

However if neither one is simply connected, I'm not so sure. To be concrete, start with $X$ as the torus, $T^2$, and $Y$ as the circle $S^1$. Using van Kampen's theorem gives $$\pi_1(T^2 \vee S^1) = \mathbb{Z}^2 \ast \mathbb{Z}$$

However, I'm not sure how to picture the universal cover of this space in any concrete way. Hatcher has a discussion of Cayley complexes, which let us get the universal cover of the figure eight pretty easily. I was thinking that may be one way to get our hands on it, but I'm not sure. I'm also not sure if that will be so nice for general $X$ and $Y$.

Does anyone have any wisdom on how to picture these spaces more concretely?

Comment: I would guess that the universal covering of $T^2 \vee S^1$ is an infinite stack of disjoint $R^2$'s with lines $R$ through each of the base points. I'm not entirely sure how to prove that assertion, it's just what I was lead to picture after trying to imagine a diagram for all the ways to walk around $T^2 \vee S^1$.

Answer (score 7):

The construction is inductive. I will use the principle that "et cetera is permitted" which I learned in freshman number theory.

Let $p \in X$, $q \in Y$ be the points which are identified to each other in $X \vee Y$. Start with a copy of the universal cover $\widetilde X$. To each lift $\tilde p$ of $p$, attach a copy of $\widetilde Y$ by identifying that $\tilde p$ to some $\tilde q$. To each unidentified $\tilde q$, attach a copy of $\widetilde X$ by identifying that $\tilde q$ to some $\tilde p$. To each unidentified $\tilde p$, attach a copy of $\widetilde Y$… To each unidentified $\tilde q$, attach a copy of $\widetilde X$… Et cetera, et cetera.

I wrote up this construction as a solution to a different problem but have been unable to locate it. It seems the question has been deleted, or my ability to search is inadequate.